# Mongodb most efficient way to find not linked children

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections, a parent and a child collection.
The parent knows which children are linked.

The parent:

```
{
   _id: ObejctId;
   linkedChildren: ObjectId[]
}
```

I now wanna find the most efficient way, to find the children which are not linked in any parent.
My current query:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'parent',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'linkedChildren',
      as: 'result',
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      result: {
        $size: 0,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
    },
  },
]
```

How can I improve this and make it more efficient?

Comment: How large are your collections? ... number of documents, etc.

Comment: This seems a canonical approach. Have you indexed the fields you used in `$lookup`?

Comment: And maybe do a premature return in the `$lookup` with `$limit: 1` if more than 1 parent can share the same child like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KVBVGk5mg_O)?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I lasted worked with Mongo, but  I don't think you can escape querying every item in your database.

If you want to improve your performance and don't want to include parent logic in the child element, you could perhaps have a collection of "Orphan" elements. The downside is that you'd have to maintain that collection, but then you wouldn't need the COLSCAN anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If the collections are not too large, this aggregation pipeline gets all `"_id"`s from the children collection, all `"linkedChildren"` `"_id"`s, and then takes the `"$setDifference"` to determine `"kidsWithNoParent"`.

N.B.:  If either collection is too large, the `"$group"` stages will exhaust allowable memory.

```js
db.children.aggregate([
  { // get all children _ids
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "kidIds": {"$push": "$_id"}
    }
  },
  { // get all linkedChildren
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "parents",
      "as": "linkedKids",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "kids": {"$push": "$linkedChildren"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { // set difference of all children _ids and linkedChildren
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "kidsWithNoParent": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {"$first": "$linkedKids.kids"},
          "initialValue": "$kidIds",
          "in": {"$setDifference": ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RrC2pWQA-oz).

Comment: Maybe use `$addToSet` instead of `$push`?

Comment: @ray I looked at that, but since there's no `"$each"` available here, even the output format is awkward.  So, thinking that the intersection of the groups of kids will almost always be an empty set, the `"$push"` is probably more performant.  But if these are _"traditional"_ families (Are there many left? Are these collections even people?) and both parents are in the collection separately, `"$addToSet"` might be better.  I think the OP will need to benchmark with his data to find out ... if even the collections are small enough for this to work.

Comment: @ray If the _"parents"_ are, say, McD's franchises, and the _"children"_ are menu items, then `"$addToSet"` might be very helpful. 